# jQuery returning undefined for parents selector in simple alert

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access a parent of the clicked item in the DOM tree, and for some reason it's not having any of it.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$('.video-icon').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('.video-space').html())
});
```

And my html:

```
<div class="video">
    <div class="video-space">
        <img src="img/video-1.jpg" alt="" class="video-img">
    </div>
    <div class="video-info">
        <div class="video-icon">
            <img src="img/video.svg" alt="" class="video-icon-img">
        </div>
        <h3 class="video-text">Watch video</h3>
        <h3 class="video-title" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxx">Toy Story Trailer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any advice on to get it working is great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.video-space` is *not* an ancestor of `.video-icon`. [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) looks for the first ancestor element matching the selector, which is why it isn't working.

You'll need something like:

```
$('.video-icon').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('.video').find('.video-space').html())
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/14/

Comment: Any ideas as to how I can target it at all?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any .video-icon being inside a .video-space in your HTML code. So when .video-icon is clicked, it tries to find a .video-space among its parents, but there are none, so it does not output anything.

Perhaps you're trying to find the sibling, so use `sibling('.video-space')` instead of parent().